# Calculating a Minkowski functional

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I have the following question:

*Let $E$ be the square in $\mathbb{R^2}$ centered at (0,0) with edge length 2, and let $p(x)$ be the Minkowski functional of E. Find $p(1,0),$ $p(x-3y)$ where $x = (1,0)$ and $y = (0,1)$ and find $p(x_{1}, x_{2})$ for arbitrary x_{1}, x_{2}.*

Now, for the first two, I've just found that the result is zero both times. Since $p(1,0) = inf\{r>0: \frac{(1,0)}{r} = (\frac{1}{r},0) \in E \} = inf\{r \in \mathbb{R}: 0 < r \le 1 \} = 0$. Obviously the other would be the same since I can use the linearity of $p(x)$ to split $p(x-3y)$ into $p(x)$-$3p(y)$ $= 0-3*0 = 0$. But for the last one, would it also just be zero or am I doing this entirely wrong?

Comment: It is only *sublinear*, not linear.

Comment: Ah thank you I made a mistake. I would still have 0 as the answer for the second one right? Since I would get $p(x-3y) \le p(x) - 3p(y)$ which would be 0 - 0 so I'd have 0 (from p being non-negative).

Answer (score 3):

$p(1,0)=\inf \{r>0:(\frac 1 r,0)\in E\}=\inf \{r\geq 1\}=1$. For any $(a,b)$ $p(a,b)=\inf \{r>0:(\frac a r,\frac b r)\in E\}=\inf \{r:|\frac a r|\leq 1,|\frac b r|\leq 1\}=\inf \{r:\max \{|\frac a r|,|\frac b r|\}\leq 1\}=\inf \{r:\max \{|a |,|b |\}\leq r\}=\max \{|a|,|b|\}$. In particular $p(x-3y)=3$.

Comment: Oh wow, I had really screwed that up, thank you so much for your help!